# A name for algorithms that perform well in an asymptotic sense, when inputs are random

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, approximation-algorithms

Is there a term for an algorithm that performs "well" (say, within a constant factor of optimality) in an asymptotic sense when a large number of random inputs are provided?  For example, say I had an algorithm for solving the travelling salesman problem, and I didn't have any guarantees on its performance for any particular input, but I could say that if we draw a large number of independent samples from a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the quality of the solution converged (almost surely, in expectation, whatever) to the optimum?

Comment: When you say "performance" do you mean how close the solution is to the optimal solution or are you talking about complexity? If the former, I have seen them called randomized $\rho$-approximation algorithms.

Comment: The former.  The only distinction I'm wondering is that, in a "randomized approximation algorithm", don't we assume that the inputs are deterministic and we just have some random number generator that helps inform our decision?  And is there a notion of asymptotic performance that comes into play?

Comment: This is closer to "average case complexity": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity